# ¿Cómo extraigo un elemento de una cadena de caracteres en Java?

Tags: java

La cadena de caracteres tiene la siguiente extructura: "4A5"
y necesito ambos números por separado para realizar operaciones matematicas y necesito también aparte la letra en medio de la cadena.

¿Como lo puedo hacer?

Comment: Bienvenido Cristian,agrega lo que has tratado de realizar, revisa [ask]. No olvides realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 1):

Este es un ejemplo relativamente sencillo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String words = "Hola mundo";
    char[] caracteres = words .toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < caracteres.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("El caracter " + i + " es " + caracteres[i]);
    }
}
```

Puedes buscar más información acerca de la clase **String**

```
String.toCharArray();
```

Donde "String" es la variable que contiene la cadena. Este te generará un vector de tipo char[ ].

**Resultado:**

```
El caracter 0 es H

El caracter 1 es o....
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando expresiones [regulares](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum) y el **split** de String [split(String regex)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), después de esto el String se convierte en un **String[]**, entonces se verifica caracter por caracter si es un numero y lo agrego a una ArrayList de String y las letras a otro, con la lista de números lo convierto a entero y hago una multiplicación:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TestArrayString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String cadena = "4A5";
        ArrayList<String> numeros = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> letras = new ArrayList<String>();

        String[] singles= cadena.split("(?!^)");



        for(String caracter: singles){
            if(TestArrayString.isInteger(caracter)){
                numeros.add(caracter);
            }else{
                letras.add(caracter);
            }
        }
        if(!numeros.isEmpty()){
            for(String numero: numeros){
                System.out.println("Esta es una multiplicación de 4*"+numero+"="+(4*Integer.parseInt(numero)));
            }
        }
        if(!letras.isEmpty()){
            for(String letra: letras){
                System.out.println("Esta es una letra: "+letra);
            }
        }



    }

    public static boolean isInteger(String s) {
        return isInteger(s,10);
    }

    public static boolean isInteger(String s, int radix) {
        if(s.isEmpty()) return false;
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if(i == 0 && s.charAt(i) == '-') {
                if(s.length() == 1) return false;
                else continue;
            }
            if(Character.digit(s.charAt(i),radix) < 0) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Esto es el resultado:

Esta es una multiplicación de 4*4=16

Esta es una multiplicación de 4*5=20

Esta es una letra: A

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un ejemplo utilizando el método `charAt()` para extraer el carácter en cualquier posición, y el método `parseInt()` para convertir una cadena en entero.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String cadena = "4A5";
    int numero1 = Integer.parseInt(cadena.charAt(0) + "");
    int numero2 = Integer.parseInt(cadena.charAt(2) + "");
    String letra = cadena.charAt(1) + "";

    System.out.println(numero1 + numero2);
  }
```